# Error adding items to ArrayList Java Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've been running into a nullPointerException while trying to add items to an arrayList. Below is the function that does that:

```
public void addToUtilityCardItems() {
        int[] utilitiesLogos = {R.drawable.kenya_power, R.drawable.nairobi_water, R.drawable.startimes, R.drawable.zuku};
        String[] utilitiesNames = {"Kenya Power", "Nairobi Water", "Startimes", "Zuku"};
        UtilitiesModel utilities = new UtilitiesModel();

        for (int i = 0; i < utilitiesNames.length; i++) {
            utilities.setUtilityLogo(utilitiesLogos[i]);
            utilities.setUtilityName(utilitiesNames[i]);
            utilityCardItems.add(utilities);
        }

    }
```

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sce.kbs.lient.FragmentTwo.addToUtilityCardItems(FragmentTwo.java:82)
            at com.sce.kbs.lient.FragmentTwo.onActivityCreated(FragmentTwo.java:56)
```

Kindly assist

Comment: My guess is that utilityCardItems is null

Comment: Are you instantiated utilityCardItems? Seems that it is not initialized and because of that you are getting NPE. Attach debugger on last line from your question.

Comment: Have you have initialised `utilityCardItems`??

Comment: I would recommend you looking at the debugging functionality of your IDE. For example for [android studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html). Then look at the value being added in line 82. One of them seems to be null.

Comment: thanks, I modified this line private List<UtilitiesModel> utilityCardItems=new ArrayList<>();, but it only adds the last item after looping, i.e., 4 similar items of the last item in the arrays

Comment: You have to create a new `UtilitiesModel utilities = new UtilitiesModel();` in each for iteration, because you are adding the same object.

Comment: Which line is line 82?

Comment: thanks, it worked as per the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add several utilities object:

```
public void addToUtilityCardItems() {
        int[] utilitiesLogos = {R.drawable.kenya_power, R.drawable.nairobi_water, R.drawable.startimes, R.drawable.zuku};
        String[] utilitiesNames = {"Kenya Power", "Nairobi Water", "Startimes", "Zuku"};


        for (int i = 0; i < utilitiesNames.length; i++) {
            UtilitiesModel utilities = new UtilitiesModel();
            utilities.setUtilityLogo(utilitiesLogos[i]);
            utilities.setUtilityName(utilitiesNames[i]);
            utilityCardItems.add(utilities);
        }

    }
```